# Python TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable. Unable to print desired number

Tags: python, string, datetime, typeerror

Using this code[image: code] I am trying to extract just the day number from this date.  In this example it would be 30.  When I try to print with the range[] function I get the error.  How can I just print this desired number?

I am unable to turn into a str function or use the range function to select my desired number.

Comment: If you want the day, it's simply `dt_m.day`.  Same thing for `year`, `month`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to extract the day, you should use .day from the datetime module.

```
dt_m = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(m_time)
print(dt_m.day)
```

The output will be the day, or in your case 30.

Answer (score 1):

datetime objects have named properties for their components, so you should be able to just reference `.day`!

```py
>>> datetime.datetime.now().day
10
```

You can see all the methods and properties of an object with `dir()`

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> from datetime import timezone
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
>>> dir(d)
['__add__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__radd__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rsub__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', 'astimezone', 'combine', 'ctime', 'date', 'day', 'dst', 'fold', 'fromisocalendar', 'fromisoformat', 'fromordinal', 'fromtimestamp', 'hour', 'isocalendar', 'isoformat', 'isoweekday', 'max', 'microsecond', 'min', 'minute', 'month', 'now', 'replace', 'resolution', 'second', 'strftime', 'strptime', 'time', 'timestamp', 'timetuple', 'timetz', 'today', 'toordinal', 'tzinfo', 'tzname', 'utcfromtimestamp', 'utcnow', 'utcoffset', 'utctimetuple', 'weekday', 'year']
```

Comment: Oh very interesting! I had no idea about the dir() command.  That will certainly prove helpful in my future efforts.  Thank you for the assistance!